# Show that $K(U) \cong K(X)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an irreducible algebraic set. Let $U$ be an Zariski open subset
of $X$. Show that $K(U) \cong K(X)$, where $K(X) = $Set of rational function on $X$.

Obviously if $U \subsetneq X$. This is infinite. Next what?

How to prove this? Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that if $f,g$ are regular functions on a variety $X$, which by definition is an irreducible algebraic set, and $f = g$ on some nonempty open subset $U \subseteq X$ then $f = g$ everywhere. This is because the set of zeros of $f - g$ is closed and dense thus must be equal to all of $X$. Therefore, given any regular function on $X$, it can be considered as a regular function on $U$ via restriction. Then the above says we can extend it because it agrees with a regular function on a nonempty open subset.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I am trying to write the answer and lets see what happens..

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence (nor how «the above» implies it) It is certainly not the case that a regular function on $U$ can be extended to a regular function on the whole of $X$. This does not work already for the simplest example where $X$ is the line and $U$ is the complement of the origin.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. However, I am not saying how to start with a regular function on $U$ and extend to a regular function on $X$, but rather the other way around. I'm simply trying to illustrate that on a variety, open subsets capture most of the data of morphisms.

Comment: Well, I have some difficulty connecting what you wrote with what was asked ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If $X=Spec(A)$, then $U$ is $Spec(A_S)$ where $A_S$ is the localization of $A$ at $S$. So $K(X)$ is the field of fractions of $A$ is equal to $K(U)$ the field of fractions of $A_S$.

Comment: Now you have to prove that $U$ is the spec of the localization :-)

Comment: (Nottice that there is no reason for an open set of $X$ to be affine; this is reflected in what you wrote in that you do not tell us what $S$ is)